# Shorten the length of your @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with DynamoDB and trying to randomly generate keys. The keys created by @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey seem to generate with 36 characters, I would like to have it only generate around 10. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you attempting to do that from AWS management console? or from your local IDE?

Comment: Local IDE, using Java I should have mentioned.

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041468/1091478) for a similar question