# Is there any way we can restrict the length of Auto generated hashKey in DynamoDb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have the below code (Java Entity class)and upon executing my java code I am able to auto-generate the unique hashkey value for my column id/myId.

Which look like this "**88a2795a-3836-4720-926a-517506b18469**".

My question: Is there any way we can restrict the length of Auto generated hashKey in DynamoDb or we can formate it.

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "test_app")
public class MyApplication {

```
private String id;

@Id
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "myId")
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Auto-increment key isn't actually a function of Dynamo...

It's an add-in to the Java SDK.  All it's doing is generating a UUID, so no it can not be shorter.

Comment: Do you have any references or documentation to support your answer?

Comment: [Here is the code in the DynamoDb SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/02ba4f48b9470226f104b9166efe4915632bcae7/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBGeneratedUuid.java#L66). Like it mentions, "The short-formed {@link DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey} may also be used for * create only."